# Cannot fetch data from my Google analytics account to a google docs

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-docs-api

I am following this [instruction](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/articles/reporting-apps-script) and I wish to read my google analytics account and write it to a google doc. after readin my account I cant get my account Id and see this error:

TypeError:cannot read property "id" from undefined:

```
  var customMetrics = Analytics.Management.CustomMetrics.list( account.id,webProperty.id );
```

Is there any one who can guide me what I am missing? Any tip is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, the error is telling  you that you are not receiving any info on those vars, account and webProperty, one of them is undefined, or both
so, because you are not showing that much code from  your project, my suggestion for now is to check to see if you enabled this:
**"Enable Google Analytics API in Apps Script"**

the service looks interesting

Comment: Thanks for that. Yes. I did but it didn't work. I used several codes and in all of them I have the connection problem. The problem is not the code that steps that I need before the code. I am missing a part that I do not know what it is.

Comment: diid you identified which one is the undefined one? account or webproperty?

Comment: Both of them are unidentified. It seems a connection problem. It can not connect and read any data from GA.

Comment: maybe an error with the lines for accessing that data (maybe the error is when you try to get the items for the account or the web property if you see below, account get items method returns an array, sometimes missing an array and trying to access it as a regular value gets you an undefined var):
**Retrieve the Authorized User's First View (Profile)**
in the instructions

Comment: I tried Retrieve the Authorized User's First View (Profile) as well and I had same error.

Comment: Let's assume my code is exact same as sample here https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/articles/reporting-apps-script